# What application can I use to synchronize several machines devices?

Tags: windows, linux, sync

I have the same files in several machines, and several locations in them (removable devices, hard disks, etc.) in Windows and Linux, what synchronize/backup system could I use to update every copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linux you could use rsync. In Windows you could use cygwin+rsync or robocopy (built-in)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Live Mesh

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-devices-help-center

Comment: Mesh is great (I use it, along with other things), but I don't believe there is a Linux client for it.